# Optimizing a update query for large data set in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query (see below) in a update trigger of a table and update certain fields on large dataset on the basis of what is currently updated in the trigger.For a set of 100000 records it is taking approx 22 sec and I want to optimize this more

```
update RED
set EDR_IsLock = @il
where RED.docid in 
      (select a.DocID
       from 
           (select distinct DocID 
            from UVD
            where UVD.UVID in (select i.UVID from inserted i)) a 
       left outer join
           (select distinct UVD.DocID 
            from UVD
            inner join UVH on UVD.UVID = UVH.UVID 
            where UVD.UVID not in (select i.UVID from inserted i) 
              and UVH.IsLock = 1) b on a.DocID = b.DocID
       where b.DocID is null)
```

PS: Table Red contains more than a trillions of records

Comment: did you try to execute it in SSMS? you can make an attempt and check the execution plan to get hints.

Comment: @lad2025 Yes this is in trigger

Comment: I am sorry but non of the answer provided below helped, the made the query more slower, let me add one thing.. the table Red have trillions of record.

Comment: You shouldn't be updating a table with *trillions of records** in the context of a trigger ....

Comment: @marc_s  Agreed but there is a requirement to make sure that everything will be updated or roll-backed and trigger guarantees that

Answer (score 3):

Try Join instead of in clause. Try below one, it might help you.

```
Update  r
Set     EDR_IsLock = @il
From    RED As r
        Join
        (
            Select  a.DocID
            From    (   Select  Distinct DocID 
                        From    UVD
                                Join inserted i On UVD.UVID = i.UVID
                    ) a 
                    left outer join
                    (
                        Select  Distinct 
                                UVD.DocID 
                        From    UVD
                                join UVH on UVD.UVID = UVH.UVID 
                        Where   UVD.UVID Not In (Select i.UVID From inserted i)
                                And UVH.IsLock = 1
                    ) b on a.DocID = b.DocID
            Where   b.DocID is null
        ) As t On r.docid = t.DocID
```

**Update:**

I am not a good explainer, But, if "Not Exists" make significance difference instead of "In Clause", then I would rewrite above query as follows:

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @UVD Table
(
    DocID           Int
)

Declare @UVDWithUVH Table
(
    DocID           Int
)

Insert Into @UVD(DocID)
Select  Distinct 
        DocID 
From    UVD As u With (Nolock)
        Join inserted i On u.UVID = i.UVID

Insert Into @UVDWithUVH(DocID)
Select  Distinct
        u.DocID 
From    UVD As u With (Nolock)
        Join UVH As uh With (Nolock) on u.UVID = uh.UVID 
Where   Not Exists (Select 1 From inserted As i Where i.UVID = u.UVID)
        And uh.IsLock = 1

Update  r
Set     EDR_IsLock = @il
From    RED As r
        Join
        (
            Select  a.DocID
            From    @UVD As a
                    Left Outer Join @UVDWithUVH As b On a.DocID = b.DocID
            Where   b.DocID Is Null
        ) As t On r.docid = t.DocID
```

In this solution, I am suggesting to use @Table variable, which will be resides inside the Ram instead of Physical Storage. And remove overhead of querying distinct inside the inner query while Join.

Try this updated one also, and would like to know, does it help you to increase the performance of your trigger.

Comment: Why on earth would you use `NOLOCK` in a trigger?!! Also, the statement that a table variable is stored in RAM is not true, it is stored in the temp db just like a temp table. See [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/7257) for more information about table variables, and their behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, you correct me for table variable stored location. And for NOLOCK, here, the NOLOCK applied to only those tables which are going to used only for comparison. So if raw data come for comparing by NOLOCK, there would be nothing dangerous. Agreed that if there is transaction critical application like banking applications then, NOLOCK should not be used. Correct me, if I am also wrong for NOLOCK.

Comment: The question is always, which is worse, incorrect data or locks. In most cases I would say incorrect data is worse, especially considering the result of the query will form the basis of an update. Using `NOLOCK` does not just give the chance of reading an uncommitted record, it can cause records to be missed completely, or read twice, or read a record that never existed. For more reading, and demonstrations of the unwanted side effects see Paul White's article [The Read Uncommitted Isolation Level](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level).

Answer (score 3):

I would personally rewrite this as:

```
UPDATE  RED
SET     EDR_IsLock = @il
WHERE   RED.DocID IN
        (   SELECT  UVD.DocID
            FROM    UVD
            WHERE   RED.DocID = UVD.DocID
            AND     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i WHERE i.UVID = UVD.UVID)
            AND     NOT EXISTS
                    (   SELECT  UVD.DocID
                        FROM    UVD AS UVD2
                        WHERE   UVD2.DocID = UVD.DocID
                        AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UVH WHERE UVH.UVID = UVD2.UVID AND UVH.IsLock = 1)
                        AND     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i WHERE i.UVID = UVD2.UVID)
                    )
        );
```

In all instances I am replacing `JOIN`, and `IN` with `EXISTS`. SQL Server has a problem with using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` to remove records, as [documented here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/), in the very best case scenario you will get equal performance to `NOT EXISTS`, but sometimes `LEFT JOIN` will be worse. `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` is not able to utilise an anti semi-join (will stop the seek/scan as soon as one record is found) in the same way `EXISTS` is.With your current method, you are selecting all records from `UVD` that match the criteria, you are then sorting them so that duplicates can be removed, then using these results to discard records found in the subquery `a`.

Similar logic applies to the `INNER JOIN`, in replacing with `EXISTS` you are telling SQL Server that you don't care what the record is in `UVH`, you just care that there is one.

The only other change I have really made is to change `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`, this could potentially be doing nothing, but `NOT IN` will cause unexpected behaviour if `NULL` records are present.

With these changes made, you should then run the query, and show the actual execution plan. This will help to identify bottle necks, and SQL Server may even suggest indexes that would speed up the query.

Comment: I would use this solution, also very well explained too + 1